# How come you can't use arguments in autocmd

Tags: vim

Let's say I have some function which puts me into Insert mode, and I want to add a cleanup function which gets called, once I leave Insert mode.
I would do something like this:

```
function! s:Foo(arg)
    augroup cleanup_group
        autocmd!
        autocmd InsertLeave * call <sid>cleanup(a:arg)
    augroup END
    " ...
endfunction
```

How come I can't do this? Also I can't use `a:arg` inside of `remaps`, which I kinda get, but why is this also not possible?
How are you supposed to do this otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass `arg` (from `s:Foo`), you can play with `:exe` instead.

Something like:

```
...
exe 'autocmd InsertLeave * call <sid>cleanup('.string(a:arg).')'
...
```